# Is it possible to get CPU usage in Cloud Run from inside the container?

Tags: node.js, docker, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-run

I'd like to add a health check endpoint that responds with a `500` if CPU usage is over X%. With my NodeJS container, I was able to get `os` and `systeminformation` working on local, but not within cloudrun. Is it possible to get the CPU usage of a container inside of cloud run from within the container?

Comment: 1) I cannot answer your question regarding CPU utilization. 2) Why do you want to return 500? That will result in Cloud Run thinking your service has failed and will result in the container being destroyed. Returning a 5xx error will make your service's behavior worse, not better. 3) In private preview, CPU-based scaling is available. The new feature is the solution that you will want to deploy.

Comment: @JohnHanley On occasion, our CPU spikes when there is some weird endless loop or some other issue in the container. we want that container to be killed. so the health check is used to say the container is no longer healthy. I am under the impression that CPU based scaling doesn't kill the container, it only increases the containers to distribute the load. Related: I'm having a ton of issues from a Cloud Run update that happened April 5th which is causing my container load to spike to over 100 containers for a service that typically has 2 (chatting with support, trying to find a fix myself)

Comment: 1) CPU scaling would add or subtract containers based on usage. 2) Throw exceptions instead of returning 5xx errors. Depending on how you have health checks configured, it can take a while to determine your service is down. 3) The real solution is to correct the problem that causes the CPU spike, not bandaids with returning or throwing errors. 4) Update your post so that the problem and your objectives are clearly defined.

Comment: @JohnHanley I 100% agree on the bandaid part, but the problem is, we didn't do any updates that would cause this issue we're seeing. And I've chatted with support and are still looking into a solution. There is quite a bit more to the problem, perhaps I should make a separate question for it. For now though, I'm just looking for a way to tell cloud run when a container is unhealthy based on CPU. CPU Scaling is on by default for CPU usage over 60% according to cloud run docs. Is there another settings I should be looking into to have cloud run manage it?

Comment: Are you working with **paid** support? I do not know of an official method to measure CPU usage within Cloud Run. The Cloud Run team is very good. They should be able to find the cause. If you can create an example that reproduces the problem, I will look at it.

Comment: @JohnHanley Yes I'm working with paid support. Funny enough, I've had a bad experience with their support almost every time. Nearly every problem I had to wait for it to resolve on its own or figure it out myself. It's been very unfortunate. But for this one, I'm kind of at a loss, so hoping they will be able to figure out what is happening. I don't know how to reproduce it tho, it's a pretty intermittent issue that appeared to start out of the blue. Still digging in to it tho!